# Spring Newbie : How can I inject a a Bean instance with various members initializations?

Tags: spring

I am Spring newbie.
I am trying to understand the dependency injection process using Autowired annotation.

For example when using Field autowiring.

```
@Autowired
private SomeInterface obj;
```

So, Spring scans now all the components to find a class which implements this interface, creates an instance of it and injects it into the my class.
I guess it uses the implementation class constructor to create the instance by default.

What I still cannot figure out is, can I inject instances with different members values.

And if I can - how can I do that?

For example (quick and dirty code):

```
interface SomeInterface(){
   int getValue();
}

@Component
class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface(){

   int n;

   @Override
   int getValue(){
     return 0;
   } 
}

class MyClass(){

    @Autowired
    private SomeInterface obj;

    ....
}
```

So Spring will use SomeInterfaceImpl default constructor to create obj,
and n memebr value will be 0.

But the idea is to inject many variations of the class, isn't it? For example for testing other values.

So, if I want to inject a SomeInterfaceImpl instance but with n = 1, can I do that?

Or am I missing the Dependency injection point, and the injection are varied only by the implementing classed of SomeInterface?

I'll be happy for explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: @timsmelik Added an exaple. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Spring's dependency injection seems to have been primarily designed with the idea that when you are using member injection, you will have only one implementation.

This can be solved with Spring's @Qualifier annotation, which you can use to specify which implementation you want injected, when there is more than one.

So, for instance, you might do this:

```
interface SomeInterface(){
   int getValue();
}

@Component("A")
class SomeInterfaceImplA implements SomeInterface(){
   int n = 0;

   @Override
   int getValue(){
     return n;
   } 
}

@Component("B")
class SomeInterfaceImplB implements SomeInterface(){
   int n = 42;

   @Override
   int getValue(){
     return n;
   } 
}



class FooClass(){
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("A")
  private SomeInterface obj;
  
  int getX() {
    return obj.getValue(); // returns 0
  }
}

class BarClass(){
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("B")
  private SomeInterface obj;

  int getX() {
    return obj.getValue(); // returns 42
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Grey. Does it enforce that the scope should be set as "prototype" in order to create multiple instances?

Comment: Do you mean instance of different implementations, or multiple instances of the same implementation?

Comment: As much as I understood the deafult bean scope is Singleton. If you say that I can select between bean A to Bean B, it means that I need to set the component scope to "prototype", shouldn't I ? Please, if I mix here concepts, please explain to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you would only need to change the scope to prototype if you wanted different instances of the same implementation in two different injections, e.g if you wanted to inject different instances of bean A into FooClass and BarClass.